# Change flow of sequence of policies using Java Script in apigee?

Tags: apigee

If i want XSLTransform-1 policy to get executed only when the URL has "tennis" keyword in it,how can i do it using Java Script policy in apigee?

URL:  http://shaleen-test.apigee.net/v1/espn--api/tennis/athletes/296?    apikey=rgnmd3naaw2qwv79fdtjgz77

Policy:XSLTransform-1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XSL async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="xsltransform-1">
    <DisplayName>XSLTransform-1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Source>response</Source>
    <ResourceURL>xsl://xsltransform-1</ResourceURL>
    <Parameters ignoreUnresolvedVariables="true"/>
  <OutputVariable>abc</OutputVariable>
</XSL>
```

XSL File:xsltransform-1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">

 <xsl:template match="/"> 


  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>PROFILE OF PLAYERS</h1> 
    <h2> <xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/name" /> </h2>
    <h3>Report Details</h3>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>PLAYER ID</th>
        <th>FIRST NAME</th>
        <th>LAST NAME</th>
         <th>FULL NAME</th>
         <th>SHORT NAME</th>
      </tr>


      <xsl:for-each select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes">
      <tr>


        <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firstName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="lastName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="fullName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="shortName" /></td>



        <!--<td><xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes/id" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes/firstName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes/lastName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes/fullName" /></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Root/sports/leagues/athletes/shortName" /></td>-->
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by have a conditional execution of the XSLT.You can use extract variables to extract a particular value from the request path.And if that variable's value is 'tennis' you can execute the XSLT Policy.

Is there any specific reason why you want to control the flow from Javascript?